# Use a global variable inside promise javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

I am new to using async functions and promise in javascript. I am trying to fetch some data which is set/created inside the async function which is returned as a promise . How do I fetch this data outside the then() function. Is there any way to do this?

```
var config={}
//global variable


async function drawGraph(graph) {
//some code
.
.
.
config={
    linkStrength: 1,
    linkDistance: 20,
    nodeStrength: -30,
    Size: 4,
    restart: reset
  };
}

makeRequest().then(data => drawGraph(data));

console.log(config.Size);
// Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `drawGraph` [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you have at least two options. A first option is using the existing [promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining):

```
makeRequest()
  .then(data => drawGraph(data))
  .then(() => console.log(config.Size));
```

A second option is using [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
const data = await makeRequest();
await drawGraph(data);
console.log(config.Size);
```

But for this above to work, [while top-level await is still not available](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await), it needs to be wrapped in an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function. You might have to do something like this:

```
async function run() {
  const data = await makeRequest();
  await drawGraph(data);
  console.log(config.Size);
}

run().then(() => console.log('Done'));
```